# Could not load Projectname.Page error on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, settings, config

I recently deployed my files to the server.  But when I am browsing the files. I am getting the error as

> *Could not load type 'Projectname.Login'.*

I am getting these error at

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Projectname.Login" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" %>
```

Please help where I am getting wrong

See the code and namespace:-

```
namespace CSRProject
```

Also see the class declaration:-

```
public partial class Login1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{}
```

Comment: IS the related dll in the bin folder?

Comment: What about your folders tree?

Comment: @InvernoMuto: Yes the dll are present there

Comment: @LPs: I did not got you..!!

Comment: Are you sure that folders on the server are organized as in your development system?

Comment: Ensure ProjectName dll is in Bin folder. Seems namespacing issue.

Comment: @LPs: Yes, I checked that. they are all organised.

Comment: @Amit: Yes the `projectname.dll` is their in Bin folder

Comment: Can you put line of code here for Login.aspx.cs where namespace is declared?

Comment: @Amit: which line of code do you want ?

Comment: Login.aspx.cs  namespace and class declaration .

Comment: @Amit :See the updated question

Comment: Check your `Inherits="Projectname.Login"` and your backend code calss is `CSRProject.Login1 ` which are not matching match those and it should work

Comment: @CoderofCode: Yes changed that but now I am getting error as ` The file '/Master.master.cs' does not exist.`

Comment: Check your all namespaces and the `aspx` pages `Inherits` tags values carefully your error lies in there.

Comment: @CoderofCode: What to check here ? I did not got you, the aspx and Inherits are the same

Comment: Check same as you check for login.aspx. Check the class name within which namespace. So for example your codebehind file is having class Class1 under namespace Namespace1 then inherits in aspx page should also have Namespace1.Class1. Also, your original question is solved now. You can close this question.

Comment: @Amit: Yes that was the issue, i resolved it. Thanks for your help. Please post it, i will mark it as answer.!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the class name within which namespace. So for example your codebehind file is having class Class1 under namespace Namespace1 then inherits in aspx page should also have Namespace1.Class1.

From the shared code it shows

```
namespace CSRProject
```

So inherits should be

```
CSRProject.Login1

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CSRProject.Login1" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs">
```